# JQuery Mobile ListView show text on multiple lines

Tags: jquery, listview, text, mobile

I'm working on a list view with jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to do something similar to this sample:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/lists/lists-formatting.html

I have a title and a long description text.
The problem is that I need the text to start a new line if the screen is too small (or text to long), what happens now is that the text gets cut and added dots ...

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">               
     <li>
     <a href="tl1.html" data-transition="fade">
     <img style="margin-left: 8px" width="80" height="80" alt="sample" src="images/sample_event.jpg" align="left"/>
     My band
     <br>
     <font style="font-size: small">
     Event description, enter the event description. Please enter the event description, event            description enter. Add a description of the event.
     </font>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!
Marco

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The way I did it was to add `white-space:normal;` to the CSS for that section. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 22):

ruthc68 from jQuery Mobile official forum answered the question:

```
<font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small" >
```

Hope this will save some time to someone :)

Answer (score 4):

1. open (jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css) and
2. replace all **white-space:nowrap** by **white-space: normal**

Comment: pretty extreme. It'll make upgrading a nightmare too

Comment: It's always a bad idea to go and alter libraries. I'd recommend not doing it!

Comment: Another way to do this, which can work in some cases, is to add to all elements: * {
white-space: normal !important;}

Answer (score 2):

Gulp.

"JQuery Mobile ListView show text on multiple lines "

I stumbled across this StackOverflow question, as I was also wondering how to do this.

However, after playing around with jqGrid Mobile, my best answer to this question is this: don't do it.

If you have a set of records, where each record contains multiple lines, then it's a much nicer user experience to write your own code.

Here's a couple of screenshots of my iPhone app, to show you what I mean.

[image]

On the first scren, where the user searches for a Company name, I *do* use jqGrid Mobile, along with a textbox where the user can type in a company name and *immediately* see the matching records in the jqGrid.

I documented how you can add this functionality to jqGrid here:

[jqGrid - Change filter/search pop up form - to be flat on page - not a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832085/jqgrid-change-filter-search-pop-up-form-to-be-flat-on-page-not-a-dialog/24528183#24528183)

On the second webpage though, I deliberately chose not to use jqGrid at all.  I found it was far more user-friendly to copy jqGrid's css styling, and create two HTML controls:

- a "header" bar, show the context of what you're seeing (your chosen Company Name, in this example)
- a scrollable list of locations, filling the rest of the screen.

Yes, I know, it means having to write more JavaScript code, but it looks fantastic on a device, and makes the most out of the limited screen space.  Notice how, in the screen above, I've scrolled down my list of locations, and Safari has automatically hidden its navigation bar (where the Back/Next/Send to buttons were shown).

Of course, it works well in this particular example because I know there won't be many records on this screen  (locations for a particular company).  By throwing away jqGrid on this screen, I've lost the ability for the user to search for, say, locations in a particular country,

But, for this app, not using jqGrid on one of the screens greatly improved useability.

I appreciate this example doesn't present any JavaScript code, but I hope the screenshots will inspire you to think outside the jqGrid box when developing apps for devices.