# jqGrid: Search form changed to be flat?

Tags: forms, search, jqgrid

This is a subject based on "[jqGrid - Change filter/search pop up form - to be flat on page - not a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832085/jqgrid-change-filter-search-pop-up-form-to-be-flat-on-page-not-a-dialog)" .
I've made the search form to be flat based on the subject , but right now I want not to show always on page , I want to show it only when the user press Search button from the jqGrid.
Can anyone give me an hint or solution how to do that, please?
@Oleg can you help me with that , please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th solution could be very close to the old one. You can use the following options of the searching dialog:

```js
overlay: 0,
drag: false,
beforeShowSearch: function ($form) {
    var $searchDialog = $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog"),
        $gbox = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid");

    $searchDialog.insertBefore($gbox);
    $searchDialog.css({
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: "auto",
        float: "left"
    })
    $gbox.css({clear:"left"});
}
```

Other options (like `closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeAfterReset: true, searchOnEnter: true, searchOperators: true` and other) can be chosen depend on your preferences.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-flat.htm) displays the searching dialog like

[image]

If you prefer to use Bootstrap CSS instead of jQuery UI CSS then one should add some additional lines:

```js
overlay: 0,
drag: false,
beforeShowSearch: function ($form) {
    var $searchDialog = $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog"),
        $gbox = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid");

    $searchDialog.insertBefore($gbox);
    $searchDialog.css({
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: "auto",
        padding: 0,
        float: "left"
    });
    $searchDialog.children(".modal-dialog").css({
        marginTop: 0,
        marginBottom: 0
    });
    $searchDialog.find(".modal-content").css({
        boxShadow: "none"
    });
    $gbox.css({clear:"left"});
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-bootstrap-fa-flat.htm) which displays:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!